# How can I get a list of all messages in Telegram group via the Bot API?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I have a bot in Telegram, which query can I get a list of all messages in a group or channel?

As I understand, requests like:

```
 https://api.telegram.org/bot_token/getUpdates?chat_id=@chat
```

Let me get only updates, but how can I get a full list of posts using only the Bot API?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's **NO** method to get previous messages like user at this time.

If I were you, I would use [forwardMessage](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#forwardmessage) method, forward it to useless channel/group like trash can, and read returned [Message](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message) object.w

Answer (score 3):

You can't. This feature doesn't implemented in current Bot API version. However you can try [Telegram API](https://core.telegram.org/api#telegram-api) for your task - method [messages.getHistory](https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.getHistory) exactly matches your demand.